# How to search in Elasticsearch based on if field A exists or if field B exists?

Tags: elasticsearch

For example

```
if(field A exists or field B exists){
    //perform action 
}
```

How to achieve this in elastic search 2.3?
Want a search query for this

Answer (score 0):

Returns documents that have at least one non-null value in the original field:

```
{
    "exists" : { "field" : "user" }
}
```

documentation: [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.1/query-dsl-exists-query.html)

Comment: I want to perform OR operation in exists

Answer (score 0):

This should get you going

```
{
   "query": {
      "bool": {
         "minimum_should_match": 1,
         "should": [
            {
               "exists" : { "field" : "fieldA" }
            },
            {
               "exists" : { "field" : "fieldB" }
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Can you show a sample document that you think should match?

Comment: doc 1 : 
{ 
name:"xyz", age:12,addr:"xxx"
}
doc2 :
{ 
name:"xyz", age:12,addr:"xxx"
}
doc 3 :
{ 
name:"xyz", age:12
}
doc 4:
{ 
name:"xyz",addr:"xxx"
}
I want to fetch all documents which has either age or addr. It should not fetch the document which doesnt have both age and addr.

Comment: You modified my query to use `name` instead of `fieldA` right?

Comment: Works fine for me and retrieves all four documents

Comment: I didnt downvote. Yeah it is working thank you so much